# If something is massless like light does it exist?

Tags: epistemology, metaphysics, reference-request, history-of-philosophy

I'm asking: If something is massless does it exis? Because in Einstein's equation E=mc2 Einstein said and I quote: If something doesn't have mass like light it would move at the speed of light.

Comment: Please give a reference for Einstein's statement.

Comment: *Ex hypothesi*, gravitons move at light speed, are massless, and exist (though some propose massive gravitons, IIRC). Moreover, massless photons and gluons can become bound as kugelblitzes and glueballs, which are massive. Conditions like negative- or imaginary-numbered mass would have exotic rate-of-motion consequences (again IIRC, tachyons, traveling faster than light, have imaginary mass, not imaginary as in nonexistent but as in *i*-theoretical).

Comment: Mass generally is taken as a function of energy, e.g. the elementary vectrons (vector bosons) that have mass have this as a function of how "hard it is" for them to push through the Higgs molasses, they exert energy in "pushing" and this energy manifests as their mass (I think). One might try, then, to equate existence with energeticness instead, although that would perhaps be an odd way to define existence...

Comment: What reasoning would lead you to suggest that everything that exists has mass? Aren't there holes, shadows, bad ideas, divisors of 12, or shades of red? All of those things seem to exist, but one of them has a mass.

Comment: Voting to close, clearly a physics question, not philosophical. Also, e=mc^2 is a simplification of a larger equation (energy-momentum equation). Look at that and you’ll see where photons fit in: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy%E2%80%93momentum_relation

Comment: Yes, it can exist. "Massless" is a shorthand term, and particles of light (photons) do have mass anyway since they have energy, see [Mass–energy equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass%E2%80%93energy_equivalence). It is only their [*rest* mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_mass) that is zero. So they would  have zero mass *if* they were at rest, except they can never be at rest. Such objects can only exist in a state of motion (at the speed of light in any inertial frame), hence Einstein's statement.

Comment: @Conifold The folks at Physics.SE say quite often that the notion of relativistic mass (what you refer to about photons having mass but not rest mass) isn’t a convention anymore. Not that you are wrong, but apparently physicists don’t talk that way anymore.

Comment: Love is _massless_ and it exists.

Answer (score 5):

The particles of the electromagnetic field are the *photons*. They have zero rest-mass, and always move with the velocity of light. There existence has been established for the first in 1905 due to Einstein's explanation of the [photoelectric effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoelectric_effect).

Possibly also the *gluons*, the particles of the strong interaction, have zero rest-mass.

See also [Do massless particles really exist?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/267196/do-massless-particles-really-exist)

Comment: There's an interesting, [pertinent discussion of gluons over at the PhysicsSE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/440971/how-do-we-know-that-gluons-travel-at-the-speed-of-light), FWIW!

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you mean by something. We know of a small number of types of fundamental particle that we believe to be massless and that we believe to exist, such as photons and gravitons. Then there is an unlimited class of things that have no mass and do not exist, such as giant pink unicorns. There is also a class of 'somethings' that are taken to exist but have no associated mass of their own, such as sound waves, which in fact are particular arrangements of particles with mass, or heat, which is in fact a label we give to the energy that collections of massive particles have as  consequence of the movement of the particles.

Comment: This answer might be improved by doing something to distance ourselves from perpetuating false impressions because of an arbitrary choice of nomenclature for "particles" over other ways to describe quantized interactions, although I'm not sure the best way to do so tersely and in a layman-friendly manner.

Comment: One could take the route of the Meinongian Jungle as an approach: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexius_Meinong - "Types of Objects"

Comment: @gs I agree. But it seems that going from photons as particles to photons as ineffable quantum entities is a long step with an unclear foothold at the end of it.

Answer (score 0):

What you're really asking for is a *criterion for reality*: when should we consider something to really exist?

In his book *The Beginning of Infinity* (chapter 1), physicist David Deutsch suggests the following criterion:

> [W]e should conclude that a particular thing is real if and only if it figures in our best explanation of something.

He also defines what a *good explanation* is: one that is "hard to vary", meaning (roughly speaking) that you can't easily change it without breaking it.

So, anything that is mentioned in a good explanation should be considered real.

Not a physicist but I imagine that applies to light as well.

'A particular thing is real if and only if it has mass' cannot be a valid criterion for reality since there are many massless things that nonetheless do exist, such as abstractions, shadows, colors, etc.

Answer (score -1):

For something to *exist*, it must be *observable*.

Light is observable, so it does exist.

Even abstract ideas are observable in the behaviour of people holding them.

Only if something has no observable effect on physical reality, it can be safely assumed to not exist.

Comment: You are confounding observable & falsifiable. For instance things inside event horizons may be unobservable even in principle, but are considered real. Consider especially cosmic event horizons in a Big Rip end-of-the-universe scenario.

Comment: That is why I used the term "safely assume". If we have no knowledge about something we can go on with our lives as if it doesn't exist.